# How to validate if in a list the object in a foreach has any atribute null but not asking individually?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to validate if inside a list of objects the object that i'm currently validating in a foreach has any atribute null without asking for every atribute individually?

I´m trying to validate null atributes inside an object but they are to much and I don´t what to ask indiviualy because the default value if the request returns null will always be 0.
Sorry if there is any mistake, but english is not my native languaje.

I was trying to do this:

```
public class OBJECT
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string U_ATRIBUTE1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime U_DATE { get; set; }
    public string U_ATRIBUTE2 { get; set; }
    public string U_ATRIBUTE3 { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
var results = await Login.Connection
    .Request("TABLE")
    .Filter("(U_ATRIBUTE eq " + item + " )")
    .GetAsync<List<OBJECT>>();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    // Here is where i´m trying to validate if any atribute is null 
    // but I don´t what to ask individually
    if (OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE1 == null)
    {
        OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE1 = "0";
    }
    if (OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE2 == null)
    {
        OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE2 = "0";
    }
    if (OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE3  == null)
    {
        OBJECT.U_ATRIBUTE3 = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use "attribute" when you mean "property". Attributes are a C# language feature that is *distinct* from Properties, you risk confusion by choosing to use the wrong term.

Comment: Can't you just change the `U_ATRIBUTEx` properties so if a null is passed in, it defaults to `0`?

Comment: Do you want to check if any property is null or set every property that is null?

Answer (score 2):

Ths will return `true` if any property of `obj` is `null`.

```
var result = obj.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetValue(obj) is null);
```